# How to use placeholder image, error image with cachedNetworkImageProvider in a container in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is code snippet of my flutter widget:

```
Container(
    width: 100.0,
    height: 100.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    border: Border.all(
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
        width: 1.0,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
    image: DecorationImage(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(_photoPath),
    ),
    ),
),
```

I want to set a **Placeholder image** and an **Error image** when network image is being loaded or not found on network path.

I am aware about `CachedNetworkImage` widget which has `imageUrl`, `placeholder` and `errorWidget` attributes but I am not able to use `CachedNetworkImage` instead of `CachedNetworkImageProvider` widget because my container's `decorationImage` `image` requires `CachedNetworkImageProvider` as value.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Your `Container` in `CachedImageNetwork`. You can use this

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: "http://notAvalid.uri",
  imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
        width: 100.0,
        height: 100.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: imageProvider,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
  placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external library ([CachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)) to do so:

```
CachedNetworkImage(   
imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/200x150",  
imageBuilder: 
(context, imageProvider) => 
    Container(
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
          image: imageProvider,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          colorFilter:
              ColorFilter.mode(Colors.red, BlendMode.colorBurn)),
     ),   
    ),   
 placeholder: (context, url) => 
   CircularProgressIndicator(),  
 errorWidget: (context, url, error) 
  => Icon(Icons.error),
),
```

Also, If you don't want any external plugin, you can do like below:

```
 child: new Container(
      child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
          placeholder: 'place_holder.jpg',
          image:url
      )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using CachedImageNetwork ı just want to change with what is appropriate in your code , NetworkImage , AssetImage etc.. until flutter last version relaised , plugin which is name CachedImageNetwork doesen't work properly.